# Export from ERP gives dates as string in excel mm-dd-yyyy need to convert to date to calculate net work days

Tags: excel, date

I need to use creation date and completion date to calculate the net working days for each row item. The dates appear to be strings. I tried to convert to date using the number type drop down but no dice.

[image: sheet example]

Comment: `DATEVALUE` formula? That dropdown applies formatting, which does not change the underlying value.

Comment: tried date value on cells and got nothing but value error.. thought that would work too.

Comment: Also tried to use substitute formula to change to / instead of - and got the same error

Comment: What is your windows regional settings short-date format?  How did the data get into your workbook?